# What is Carmageddon: Max Damage?

Tags: carmageddon-max-damage, carmageddon-reincarnation

Is [Carmageddon: Max Damage](http://store.steampowered.com/app/505170/) an improved version of [Carmageddon: Reincarnation](http://store.steampowered.com/app/249380/) (seems to have been pulled from sale)? There's not much information on the store page.
[According to the developer](https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791435278150/announcements/detail/652264647500852765) Max Damage is free for Steam owners of Reincarnation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://www.dsogaming.com/news/carmageddon-max-damage-out-on-steam-available-for-free-to-all-owners-of-carmageddon-reincarnation/) article:

> Stainless Games has announced the release of Carmageddon: Max Damage on Steam. The game comes with a 33% discount until November 3rd, and owners of Carmageddon: Reincarnation will receive Max Damage for free. It is basically an improved version of Reincarnation as the latter is no longer available for purchase on Steam.
>   Carmageddon: Max Damage features over 30 cool custom killing machines, each with their own highly distinctive character, 10 large open environments to explore, a host of moving targets to hunt down for points, including pedestrians in wheelchairs & mobility scooters, cyclists, bears and aliens.
>   The game comes with a career mode with 6 different event types, a multiplayer with 4 online event types, a fully featured action replay mode and with over 90 crazy PowerUps.

Comment: Metro confirms: https://web.archive.org/web/20161029130507/http://metro.co.uk/2016/07/08/carmageddon-max-damage-review-armageddon-out-of-here-5994839/